# non-lethal weapons to scare stray dogs?

Tags: dogs

I have the recurring following issue: while I walk with my dogs we are often attacked by group of stray dogs.

As I want obviously to avoid any fight and any contact with these dogs I am looking for non lethal weapons to scare these dogs away.

So far I have considered:

1. Electric baton

   - very efficient against dogs but I don't want to carry that with me all the time (and only to be used against dangerous stray dogs). My goal is more to scare them.
2. Pepper spray

   - not very efficient and not easy to use in case of wind, etc.
3. Air horns

   - I don't see that scaring the dogs.
4. Sonic guns

   - these guns (like [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000IBRI2Y)) are supposed to emit infrasounds or ulrasounds into the direction where the gun is pointed and in such a way that dogs are 'extremely' scared. But it turns out it doesn't work at all.

Are there any other non lethal anti-dog weapons that I could use?

EDIT: I am about to test **bullwhips**... I think it may work well.

Comment: Please review [How do I protect my dog from other dogs that are loose when we're walking](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1910/how-do-i-protect-my-dog-from-other-dogs-that-are-loose-when-were-walking). If it answers your question we can close this one as a duplicate.

Comment: no, in fact the answers relates to dogs behaviours , socializing dogs , leash laws... I am really trying weapons that's the only thin that may work.Again, in my place, groups of 10 to 20 agressive street dogs are really common, police do not care at all ( and in fact nobody cares at all )... BTW we have also bears etc...

Comment: Be careful to not hurt your own dog too.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to attack the dogs with the weapon, usually just holding it can scare them away.

Usually, I can scare away stray dogs by picking up any big piece of trash from the floor, like a piece of wood, a lose tree branch, or a jacket and waving it around.

They might get scared, if not, step strong to the floor and gesticulate for the to go away or get something noisy and hit it to the floor several times. Swimming pool spaghetti (or however you call it :p) is the best choice.

[image]

You can also make yourself look bigger by breathing in a lot of air and opening your arms while shouting to them. Show authority and they can get scared and respect you.

But never really attack them, because they can counter-attack.

Answer (score 0):

I love dogs. But to silence a very noisy dog that my neighbour had but neglected, I remember buying an ultrasonic gun in the UK. It worked well. Even at a distance of 100 metres, I could see the dog's reaction. He quietened down, cringed and moved away looking dazed. It did not make me feel good but neither did the loud barking all day long.

Answer (score 0):

I bought a gel rifle and it seems to do the trick...it's a motorized water gun that shoots non toxic water pellets that crumble on contact. Has single shot and full auto. The pellets don't break human or dog skin (might on a bird tho) but it stings good enough to make em take off running (I have one that shoots 8 rounds a sec with a 550 round drum mag). Cops and local authorities (I live in small town) said it was fine cause its legally just a water gun and it's the same thing as using a hose to scare off a dog. Check the laws in your town tho. You can find a decent one on Amazon from $60-120. Just get one with bright colors so the cops don't get scared ( mines an all white ak 47 with see thru blue stock and mag)